# Question on equality in ODEs

Tags: abstract-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations

I've been doing some reading in differential geometry and it's caused me some confusion over the objects involved in differential equations. Consider $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ and a first order ODE

$$\frac{df}{dt}\Bigg|_t=g(f,t)$$

The R.H.S evaluates on $\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ while the L.H.S $\frac{df}{dt}\Big|_t=f_*(\frac{d}{dt}\Big|_t)$ evaluates on $\mathbb{R}\rightarrow T\mathbb{R}$ so it seems to me that we stating that unlike objects are equal. It seems to me that on the L.H.S we are really interested in the 'natural' map $v(t)\frac{d}{dt}\Big|_t\mapsto v(t)$, is this correct and should it be made explicit? (and without this is a diffeomorphism more appropriate than an equality?)

It's worth mentioning that the partial derivative of $f:M\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ with coordinate system $x$ is defined by a in terms of the directional derivative

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^i}\Bigg|_p := D_i(f\circ x^{-1})(x(p))$$

and perhaps this is from where my confusion is arising. If I plug this definition into the above problem I get $\frac{df}{dt}\Big|_t=f'(t)$ which appears to resolve my issue, but I've chosen to reject this answer! This definition appears to be useful in that it tells explains how to compute the value of the tangent vector, but still leaves me befuddled with respect to the objects at play.

Is there something else that I am missing? Anything to alleviate my confusion will be much appreciated.

*Note: The notation that I'm using (should be) consistent with that used by Spivak.*

---

#### Edit 1:

From the answers I've received it seems that we do make this identification is between $\mathbb{R}$ and $T\mathbb{R}$ implicitly. Mathematical 'Identifications' such as these feel very 'algebraic' to me - **which leads me to a second (and less well formed) question: Is there a nice way to describe this using some algebraic theory of morphisms?**

Comment: If I understand well your question, you have to remember that a real linear map $x \mapsto ax$ is fully defined by the real $a$. Hence, you can identify $df/dt(t)$ with a real. This is by the way what we all do when considering the derivative of a real map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, we can always make the identification between $T\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}$.

Secondly, the normal derivative for normal functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ have the usual derivate $\frac{d}{dx}f(x)\big|_{x=t}$ which simply map to $\mathbb{R}$. The usual derivative is just a real number.

Comment: I was troubled by the fact that this identification was never made explicit (especially since we don't have the luxury of a natural map between the base and tangent space on a general manifold) but I guess $\mathbb{R}^n$ is just special...

Answer (score 0):

The implicit identification between $\mathbb{R}$ and $T\mathbb{R}$ already happens in this formula $\tfrac{d}{dt}\Big|_tf = f_*(\tfrac{d}{dt}\Big|_t)$. Actually, if you didn't bring it up, your original ODE is an equality between objects of the same type $\mathbb{R}$.